# AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.plotly' has no attribute 'offline'

Tags: python, plotly

I am quite struggling with plotly offline mode in jupyter notebook.  I used to use import plotly.plotly as py and then use py.offline.plot().  Now it tells me plotly.plotly is depreciated and want me to use chart_studio.plotly. Now I don't know how to use offline mode for chart_studio.plot.  I either got an error of Authentication is required or chart_studio doesn't have offline mode. I just want to plot some figures in jupyter notebook using plotly. How can I fix the issue? Thanks

```
import chart_studio.plotly as py
from chart_studio.grid_objs import Grid, Column
import plotly.figure_factory as FF
import pandas as pd
import time
import pickle

filename_pickle='dataset.pkl'
try:
    dataset=pd.read_pickle(filename_pickle)
except FileNotFoundError: 
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
    dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
    dataset.to_pickle(filename_pickle)

table = FF.create_table(dataset.head(10))
#py.iplot(table, filename='animations-gapminder-data-preview')
py.offline.iplot(table)

Previously: I use plotly.plotly 

import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF

# chart_studio is for online mode only
# import chart_studio.plotly as py
# from chart_studio.grid_objs import Grid, Column
# import plotly.figure_factory as FF

import pandas as pd
import time
import pickle

filename_pickle='dataset.pkl'
try:
    dataset=pd.read_pickle(filename_pickle)
except FileNotFoundError: 
    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv'
    dataset = pd.read_csv(url)
    dataset.to_pickle(filename_pickle)

table = FF.create_table(dataset.head(10))
#py.iplot(table, filename='animations-gapminder-data-preview')
py.offline.iplot(table)

then I got an error of 
ImportError: 
The plotly.plotly module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.plotly module instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to `import plotly` not `plotly.plotly` and call the `offline.iplot` with your chart at the parameter as shown in my example:

```
import plotly  
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Scatter(x=[1,2,3,4], y=[1,2,4,3])]

plotly.offline.iplot(data)
```

Comment: Thanks as11. it worked. but one more question,  I tried to do:  from plotly.grid_objs import Grid, Column and I still got an error like this. could you please help again? ThanksImportError: 
The plotly.grid_objs module is deprecated,
please install the chart-studio package and use the
chart_studio.grid_objs module instead.

Comment: Could you post that as another question? It will make the error and your code easier to see.

Comment: Yes, I just post a new question, please help, Thanks, I appreciate it